# Select a class Inside of a table in css (limited css and html on wikia)

Tags: html, css

I am extremely sorry if this question has been asked before. I have tried searching and have found some things that are similar, but they haven't worked. I am also very new to css and possibly just not knowledgeable enough to apply them to my situation. I also am not confident that I know the correct terminology. I really appreciate your patience with me and any help that can be given.

I need to use only css to change the color of all things with the class .spoilerbox when a user clicks on a button. This is on wikia, so I can not use javascript and some elements of html are restricted. I actually have been successful in doing this, the problem comes from when the items that need to changed are placed inside tables. I need to change the color of all of these things in all the tables with one click. I'm guessing that this is an issue of targeting the items correctly.

I have a codepen set up to experiment with [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQKOWo). Wikia uses different symbols for the table, but from what I see they basically directly act as the html code I have put in the codepen.

```css
table {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.spoilerbutton {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #653F03;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0; 
}
.spoilerbox { 
    display: block;
    transition: all 0s 9999999s;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #653F03;
    padding: 3px; 
    width: 100px; 
    position: relative;
}

.spoilerboxname {
    transition: all 0s 9999999s;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    font-size: x-small; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: white; 
    padding: 0 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px 0;
    background: #653F03;
    z-index: 10;
}
.spoilerbutton:active ~ .spoilerbox {
   transition: all 0s; 
   background:#8b0000;
}
.spoilerbutton:active ~ .spoilerbox * .spoilerboxname {
   transition: all 0s; 
   background:#8b0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="spoilerbutton">Toggle</div>
<table>
 <td>
   <table>
      <td>
     <div class="spoilerbox"><div style="border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 90px;">Image<div class="spoilerboxname"><font color=#cccccc size="1">Name</font></div></div></div>
     </td>
  </table>
 </td>
</table>

<div class="spoilerbox"><div style="border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 90px;">Image<div class="spoilerboxname"><font color=#cccccc size="1">Name</font></div></div></div>
```

So the top box in the example is inside the table while the second is not. When the "button" is clicked it changes the color of the bottom one, but not the top one. In the actually page all the boxes are in tables. There are many tables on this page with multiple of these boxes, some with the class "spoilerbox" and some without. Only the ones with the class should change.

I have already posted this over on wikia's help forum, but have not got any responses on the code. I know this would be easier with javascript, and there is a process where one can request javascript be unlocked on the wikia. I was hoping to avoid that, but if its not possible any other way, then that is next.

I am really sorry for asking what I am sure, is a dumb, obvious question. So please forgive a completely self taught newbie. But I am truly stumped. Thank you very much for any insight you can give.

Edit: Alright, I think I have figured out a part of the problem. The character box outside of the table is a sibling to the button, but when I place it inside the table it becomes a decedent of that sibling. If I give the table an id then I can do this:

```
.spoilerbutton:active ~ #mytable * .spoilerbox {
   transition: all 0s; 
   background:#8b0000;
}
```

This works in the example of codepen, I havn't tried it on the wikia yet.

Comment: is the <table> inside the <table> on purpose? Or can this be removed?

Comment: I think that was used to center and line up the character boxes. It could probably be removed. [This is the page](http://the-amber-sword.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Characters) that I wish to use it on. The code for the individual boxes is in a template, but you can see how the tables are.

Comment: The original code was taken from another wikia and adapted for this one, so I just didn't change things that seemed to work. I'm guessing the the proper spacing could be duplicated with a single table by playing around with the style settings.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the tilde (~). This is a [subsequent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators). It is looking at siblings of the button, but not descendants of the siblings. To fix this, you can simply add an additional rule that will traverse into the siblings by using an asterisk (*).

```
.spoilerbutton:active ~ .spoilerbox,
.spoilerbutton:active ~ * .spoilerbox {
    ...
}
.spoilerbutton:active ~ .spoilerbox * .spoilerboxname,
.spoilerbutton:active ~ * .spoilerbox * .spoilerboxname {
    ...
}
```

Run the code below and you'll see it changes both boxes when the button is clicked.

```css
table {
    font: 1em sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.spoilerbutton {
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #653F03;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0; 
}
.spoilerbox { 
    display: block;
    transition: all 0s 9999999s;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #653F03;
    padding: 3px; 
    width: 100px; 
    position: relative;
}

.spoilerboxname {
    transition: all 0s 9999999s;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    font-size: x-small; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: white; 
    padding: 0 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px 0;
    background: #653F03;
    z-index: 10;
}
.spoilerbutton:active ~ .spoilerbox,
.spoilerbutton:active ~ * .spoilerbox {
    transition: all 0s; 
    background:#8b0000;
}
.spoilerbutton:active ~ .spoilerbox * .spoilerboxname,
.spoilerbutton:active ~ * .spoilerbox * .spoilerboxname {
    transition: all 0s; 
    background:#8b0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="spoilerbutton">Toggle</div>
<table>
 <td>
   <table>
      <td>
     <div class="spoilerbox"><div style="border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 90px;">Image<div class="spoilerboxname"><font color=#cccccc size="1">Name</font></div></div></div>
     </td>
  </table>
 </td>
</table>

<div class="spoilerbox"><div style="border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 90px;">Image<div class="spoilerboxname"><font color=#cccccc size="1">Name</font></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @posit labs.  I spent a good hour trying to troubleshoot this for the user haha. much appreciated for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured out that I had the combiner wrong and was able to fix it by using an id to select the table (see my edit above), but I like your answer so much more. I did not know that combiners could be... well "combined." Thank you so much for your time and effort!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept the answer. This will give me some points, AND (more importantly) it will help other users know the solution worked.